# iFrame doesn't respond with jQuery plugin iziModal.. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

[iziModal official](http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com/)
As in the official sample, make iFrame if I press a button
...Not, I want to make iFrame appear when I press `section`.
I would like to have details displayed in the modal window when I push the collection of works.

### Like this

[image: push]

⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎

[image: &iframe!]
How can I implement it?

---

### Below, my code that doesn't work

jQuery, izimodal.css, izimodal.js are properly included.
(The content of iFrame is the html file that I have.)

HTML

```
<div class="list">
<div class="items">
 <section class="item item1" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-1.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/1.png" alt="1" />
   <h2>title1</h2>
   <p>description1 description1</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item2" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-2.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/2.png" alt="2" />
   <h2>title2</h2>
   <p>description2 description2</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item3" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-3.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/3.png" alt="3" />
   <h2>title3</h2>
   <p>description3 description3</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item4" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-4.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/4.png" alt="4" />
   <h2>title4</h2>
   <p>description4 description4</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item5" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-5.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/5.png" alt="5" />
   <h2>title5</h2>
   <p>description5 description5</p>
 </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
// In case of item1
$(document).on('click', '.item1', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#iframe').iziModal('open');
});
  $("#iframe").iziModal({
  iframe: true,
  width: '98%',
  ifremeHeight: '98%',
  zindex: '10',
  iframeURL: "data-1.html",
  group: 'works',
  overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
});
```

Comment: The documentation seems to only talk about `<button>` and `<a>` as possible trigger elements. Is that an issue to wrap the `<section>` with an `<a>` having the attributes it needs? It would be quite a simple walk-around... I don't think you could have another `<a>` inside the `<section>` anyway.

Comment: *«immovable code»* ?? Please explain.

Comment: Omg! So how do I do what I want to do (display the details in the modal window when I pressing the collection of works)? I'm sorry, I wanted to say "the code that doesn't work". It seems that it has ended up become wrong meaning in Google translation..